# viewController not changing to LandScape mode in ipad

Tags: ipad, xcode4, landscape

i am developing ipad related app.Login Screen not change to Landscape mode,i change Xib and used shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation also but its didn't work out .can u help where the mistakes is there.i want app only landscape.[image: Login popup image]

Comment: What are the values in your `Info.plist` for the the `suported orientations`?

Comment: In support orientation interface 2 items there 1.Landscape (bottom home button) 2.Landscape (top home button) and supported  interface orientations (ipad) Landscape(left home button)